# Drupal query fields

Tags: database

I have to implement the following SQL query in Drupal.

```
select col1, col2, 'ABC' as col3 from Table1 where col1 = 0;
```

In my case, it may be something like this.

```
query->fields('n', array('nid', 'type',1 as 'sort_order'));
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [addExpression](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3AaddExpression/7.x) method, which is unfortunately not chainable.
The snippet that would make it work is the following.

```
$query = db_select('Table1', 't1')
  ->fields('t1', array('col1', 'col2');
  ->condition('col1', 0,'=')
$expression= $query->addExpression('ABC', 'col3');
$query->execute()
  ->fetchAssoc();
```

For more information on expressions, here is the official documentation:
https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/database-api/dynamic-queries/expressions

Comment: Hi, did you test if it is working for you ?

Comment: Great @bincy. I was just about to test it, because I hand-wrote it , without testing. Basically for future reference,  you can use addExpression to do all of those non-standard selections.

Comment: Got it! That was really a new information for me.Thanks :)

Comment: Super, I've updated the asnwer with some links, you might want to take a look for future use cases :). Have a nice day